# Reduce the number of queries

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have seperate queries but i need to reduce the no so put all in one

```
 select   count(applicant_id)  as registered from student_application where filter_status=0 AND
  select  count(applicant_id) as filer_select  from student_application where filter_status=1 AND 
   select  count(applicant_id) as filter_reject  from student_application where filter_status=2
```

but  this shows some errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select 
count(case when filter_status = 0 then applicant_id else null end) as registered,
count(case when filter_status = 1 then applicant_id else null end) as filer_select,
count(case when filter_status = 2 then applicant_id else null end) as filer_reject
from student_application;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8051ee/1)

Comment: Your question has the CodeIgniter tag but doesn't mention it, just the SQL. How you would do this in CI, if you're not just passing the raw query in SQL, depends on whether you're using an ORM and which one.

Comment: how to use case in join and multiple where conditions

Comment: @Rose Please share the scenario. so that i help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use group_by, with the where clause if you're looking for a subset rather than all possible values of filter_status:

```
SELECT filter_status, COUNT(*)
FROM student_application 
WHERE filter_status in (0, 1, 2) 
GROUP BY filter_status;
```

Comment: Thanks to Ullas for the initial formatting edit, but others, please do not edit this to change the query (particularly when you break it by omitting parens). If you have something to add, please do so with a comment.

Comment: i want to sepearate this 3

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This query returns three rows (assuming applications exist for all statuses); each contains a filter_status and a count. You can use conditionals or aliases to change the names or values of the returned columns, but the basic premise is that you're getting a count of rows in the table that match filter_status=x for each x in (0, 1, 2). So it is separating them, just into rows rather than into columns in your result. The handling will be different but the data is the same.

Comment: right...but i want 3 columns like register,select and reject=>0 register,1-select 2 reject

Comment: If there's a technical reason you need columns rather than rows, you will need to build the query entirely differently. But I think this is a more idiomatic and probably efficient approach to getting counts by column value.